# Discontinuous source for transport PDE - just the understanding remains.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

how do solve the following problem?
$$u_t + \frac{1}{3} c_t = f(x), \qquad t>0,\quad x \in \Re \\
u(x,0)=0, \qquad x \in \Re\\
f(x) = \left\{\matrix{0,\quad |x| \geq 1\\ 1-x^2,\quad -1\leq x\leq 1}\right.$$

The general solution to transport equations like this is
$$u(x,t)=g(x-c t)+\int_0^tf(x-c(t-s)) ds,$$
but since $f(x)$ is discontinuous, I'm having difficulties writing a solution explicitly. When I have Maple use
$$u(x,t)=\int_0^t \max[f(x-c(t-s)),0] ds,$$
it works, but it's very unsatisfying, since I have a hard time justifying it.
Help in understanding it will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have a definition for $f(x)$. Use that definition to write out $f(x-c(t-s))$. For what value of $s$ is $f=0$ (assuming $x,t$ are fixed)? You can ignore those in your integral. For what's left, you can use that $f(x) = 1-x^2$, so $f(x-c(t-s)) = 1-(x-c(t-s))^2$, which is just a quadratic polynomial in $s$ and should be easily integrated.

Comment: Let me just understand you here:

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let me just understand you here:
$f(x-c(t-s))=0$ when $3-3x+t \geq s \geq -3-3x+t$, if I plug the argument into the first condition and solve for s. When I ask Maple to use these as the boundaries on the integral, I get a constant value (that is, not the right answer). How do I ignore these values for s in the integral exactly? Thanks.